# 500 internal Server error when configuring python cgi

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have been trying to run a simple python script `hello.py` with CGI but am getting 500 Internal Server Error.

My python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello World - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello World! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

The directory which i have the python script running is in `/var/www/crunchworld`.The conf file which i enabled is in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/crunchworld.conf

The conf file looks like

`<Directory /var/www/crunchworld>`

`Options +ExecCGI`

`AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`

`Options All`

`AllowOverride All`

`Order allow,deny`

`Allow from all`

`</Directory>`

I have cgi enabled and given the necessary permission for the file hello.py but its still showing me internal server error.When i checked the logs i see

End of script output before headers: hello.py

I have researched about the error and give appropriate permissions for the file but it doesnt work.

Any help would be so much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Further changes i have made**.

1. I have added `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py` in my crunchworld.conf file.

2.I have given permission for the file hello.py

3. I have symlinked `/etc/apache2/conf-available/crunchworld.conf` in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled`

4.I had already installed python2.7 on the path `/usr/bin/python2.7`  and i have also tried using `#!/usr/bin/env python` but still it doesnt work.

Upon checking the logs i found `End of script output before headers: hello.py, referer: http://localhost/`

Thank you for your recommendations but it is still showing 500 internal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CGI script must also output header information.

The minimum required is the `Content-type` header -- which in this case should be set to `text/html`.

Add this to the *start* of your CGI script (before you print anything else).

```
print 'Content-type: text/html\n'
```

Take note of the extra trailing newline -- its necessary to leave at least one blank line between the header(s) and the content itself.

**Update:**

For further troubleshooting, do the following:

1. Make sure your CGI script has the correct permissions set: `chmod 0755 hello.py` just to be sure.
2. Your script appears to be `.py` whereas your apache config appears to only specify `.cgi` files. Your `AddHandler` should be `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py`.
3. You should symlink your `/etc/apache2/conf-available/crunchworld.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` if you haven't already done so. Do so by running the following: `cd /etc/apache2/conf-enabled; sudo ln -s ../conf-available/crunchworld.conf`.
4. Always remember to *restart* apache if you make any changes to your apache config: e.g. `sudo service apache2 restart`.
5. Check that your hashbang line is correct. Does `/usr/bin/python2.7` exist? You can try setting instead to `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python2`. (Or better yet, switch to `python3` if possible on your system).
6. Check the apache error logs once again. E.g. `tail -20 /var/log/apache2/error.log` (or wherever your logs are).
7. You can attempt further debugging with the `cgitb` module (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgitb.html).

Comment: i have added it but it doesnt solved the issue ..Still its showing internal server error!

Comment: @avinash-babu I've added some further debugging steps in my answer which may assist you. If your problem persists, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65368312/edit) your question with details on the steps you carried out, and the exact log information or errors you found. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help so far.But its still showing the same error from localhost..I have edited my question as you said..

Comment: Does it work when you run it on the command-line directly: `./hello.py`? Also, what does `ls -ld . hello.py` show?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 avinash avinash 264 Dec 20 13:35 hello.py  (result of ls -ld hello.py)

Comment: And there are no other error lines in the apache log? Also, apache will run it like this: `./hello.py`, so check that it works by running it like that with only `./` in front -- which will use the interpreter in the hashbag line.

Comment: when i run /hello.py it gives me /usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory..I run python scripts as python2.7 <filename>.. I guess this might be the problem..What should i do in this case to make it work ??..Should i install python on /usr/bin/env ?..Thanx for your help so far

Comment: I don't know where your Python is installed on your system; it could be in `/usr/local/bin` instead. Run `which python2` and `which python2.7` to get a suitable (Python 2) version.

Comment: I have already tried that before and added the path (/usr/bin/python2.7) to the hello,py file as #!/usr/bin/python2.7..but still it doesnt work