# Apache "AH01215: (8)Exec format error" when attempting to run python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, cgi

This is a duplicate question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41082302/ah01215-8-exec-format-error-exec-of-var-www-python-hello-py-failed-var), however none of the answers there worked for me. I have done a lot of research into this and am completely stumped.

I am running a super simple python script called `/var/www/cgi/test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import cgitb


print('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n')
print("Hello world")
```

However when I attempt to access this through my server at: https://server.com/cgi/test.py I get the following message:

[image]

This obviously doesn't tell me much, so I checked the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file and found the following:

```
[Tue Jan 25 11:55:10.622681 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 29052] [client REDACTED] AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/cgi/test.py' failed: /var/www/cgi/test.py
[Tue Jan 25 11:55:10.623144 2022] [cgi:error] [pid 29052] [client REDACTED] End of script output before headers: test.py
```

Following my research online, I have tried and done the following:

- I have added the necessary configuration lines into the apache config file at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. It looks like the following (I initially just had the `ScriptAlias` as I'm fairly certain that's all that's needed but it wasn't working so I added the `<Directory>` config too:

```
#   work with the default configuration.

ScriptAlias /cgi/ /var/www/cgi/


<Directory "/var/www/cgi">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
</Directory>


# Global configuration
#
"/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" 235L, 7355C
```

- Restarted apache using `sudo service apache2 restart` since changing the config file
- Changed the permissions of `test.py` to be `chmod 777 test.py` (overkill I know, but just in case)
- Ensured the shebang is correct with `which python3` returning `/usr/bin/python3`
- I symlinked my `crunchworld.conf` as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65368411/9546874)

Perhaps even more I'm forgetting. I'm truly at a loss, I feel like I've exhausted every avenue.

Does anyone have any idea why this error is still occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

from

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Maybe this works?

Comment: It doesn't. I actually had it that way around the first time but thought having it the same as `which python3` would help clear up confusion